# ssh port forwarding / security risk

Tags: security, ssh, port-forwarding

I want to access a web application running on a web server behind my office firewall from an external machine.

We have a bastion host running sshd that is accessible from the Internet.

I want to know if this solution is a bad idea:

- Create an account on the bastion host with shell=/bin/false and no password ('testuser')
- Create a ssh RSA key on the external machine
- Add the public RSA key to the testuser's authorized_keys file
- ssh to the bastion host from the external host using: ssh -N 8888:targethost:80
- run my tests from the external host
- shut down the ssh tunnel

I understand that if my RSA private key were compromised then someone could ssh to the bastion host.  But are there other reasons this solution is a bad idea?

thank you!

Comment: Personally I think /sbin/nologin is more appropriate than /bin/false

Comment: Not all distributions have nologin.  Slackware 10, for example.  They're both appropriate solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I checked a few distros I'm using before commenting to make sure I wasn't mistaken. Never actually used Slackware.

Comment: You might protect the SSH private key with a password in order to reduce risk of compromise.

Comment: I suggest you to harden the bastian host using procedures from an answer of mine. Please, check here: https://serverfault.com/a/980084/293407

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a pretty secure setup, I use it myself. You will need to add '-L' to your command:

```
ssh -N -L 8888:targethost:80
```

As long as you don't use the '-g' option, only your client machine can access the port forward.

What I would recommend also is to make sshd on the bastion host listen on a non-standard port. If you are listening on a standard port, the attack traffic sometimes can eat up considerable amounts of CPU.

Also choose a good passphrase for your ssh key, and enter it only on trusted machines. Preferably Linux, it is less trivial to install keyloggers on Linux.

Comment: I would go one step further and say do `ssh -N -L 127.0.0.1:8888:targethost:80` (specifying that the local listener should bind to localhost rather than glomming all your IPs).  This prevents someone on your local network from stumbling on port 8888 on your workstation and doing Bad Things.

Comment: Don't change the port, filter the traffic.

Comment: @voretaq7 Unless you explicitly specify the '-g' option, specifying 127.0.0.1 is redundant. You can try the command and then 'netstat -tnlp' if you're not convinced :)

Comment: @Prof. Moriarty - True, but I'm paranoid (and you never know when some brain-dead person will put "GatewayPorts yes" in ssh_config: more obvious stupidity has made it into released systems :)

Comment: @voretaq7 OK, you're right :) If you want good security, you need to be paranoid!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessarily a bad idea. Put SSH on a port other than 22 and you'll make it a little more obscure for script kiddies to find, and if you're testing from a laptop computer externally I'd encrypt things on the drive so if it's stolen/lost/etc. you don't need to worry about the data being compromised. Otherwise the tunnels should help keep things being being intercepted between the bastion host and the laptop on the public webbertubes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: @warner: all things being equal, running ssh on a different port does not create a security risk. Assuming you still take the other appropriate security measures you would take anyways I don't see how it is a problem.

Comment: It does not create additional risk but it is still a haphazard solution.  A kluge at best.  If you want to minimize the footprint, use packet filtering.

Comment: @einstiien: You're right, as long as you select a port < 1024. Also consider using port knocking instead.

Comment: I never implemented port knocking, but it does add an additional layer of security which might be worth it.

Comment: @Warner: it is security through obscurity, but I can also tell you that we've seen a huge drop by changing the port, and most scripts first attack using known ports. If you're being *targeted* for an attack it's little help. But if you want to reduce the log entries for failed attacks, just shift the port to another other than default.

Comment: Changing the default port from 22 to something arbitrary helps a lot to cut down on log spam by dumb scanning scripts. No added security, but I'd still recommend doing it.

Answer (score 0):

[Stunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stunnel) could be a good alternative. You wouldn't need an account on the machine, and you can still authenticate the client with a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You have proposed a pretty secure solution.
Additional security hardening steps for the host that is exposed:

1. Only allow inbound on services you know you need (allow only
   inbound tcp 22)
2. Enable automatic security updates with unattended-upgrades or yum-cron (update the config files so these services actually apply updates as they come out)
3. Do not transmit your private key through insecure means such as email or slack
4. Implement fai2ban so the bots scanning the whole internet stop knocking at the door (or better yet create a firewall whitelist of your trusted source ips)
5. Your suggestion of only allowing port forwarding by setting the shell to /bin/false or /sbin/nologin is excellent general advice for setting up bastion hosts, but makes remote administration of the machine challenging and might be overkill for your use-case.